# Django Admin Form Limit Dropdown Options

Tags: django, django-forms, django-admin

So in the Django admin I have an object change form like so:

```
class SurveyChoiceField(forms.ModelChoiceField):
    def label_from_instance(self, obj):
        return u'{0} - {1}'.format(obj.id, obj.name)


class BlahAdminForm(forms.ModelForm):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super(BlahAdminForm, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        surveys = Survey.objects.filter(deleted=False).order_by('-id')
        self.fields['survey'] = SurveyChoiceField(queryset=surveys)


class BlahAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    form = BlahAdminForm
```

and I would like to limit the dropdown to surveys of a certain type based on the blah. Something like

```
blah_id = self.blah.id
blah_survey_type = Blah.objects.filter(id=blah_id).get('survey_type')
surveys = Survey.objects.filter(deleted=False, type=blah_survey_type).order_by('-id')
```

but I'm not sure how to get the `id` of the Blah in the `BlahAdminForm` class.

Comment: That is the `id` of the instance, so in the form `self.instance.id` (after the `super(..)` call). This `id` can be `None` is case a *new* `Blah` is constructed.

Comment: @WillemVanOnsem Exactly what I needed. Write it up as an answer and I'll be happy to accept. Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A Django `ModelForm` has an `instance` which is the `Blah` instance it will create or edit. In case you edit an instance, the instance is passed through the `instance` parameter when creating the form. In case you create a new instance, then the instance is typically constructed in the `super(BlahAdminForm, self).__init__(..)` call (but has an `id` equal to `None`, since it is not yet saved).

You thus can obtain a reference to the instance that the form is editing, or a its `id` with:

```
class BlahAdminForm(forms.ModelForm):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super(BlahAdminForm, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        blah_id = self.instance.id
        # ...
```

You can thus use this `self.instance` in the constructor, or in other methods to inspect (and alter) the instance the form is handling.